# Can R workspace be copied from one machine to another?

Tags: r, copy, history, workspace

I am using two different machines, one with win 7 home another win 7 professional.  I have R 32 bit installed in both.  I worked in one.  To port the files from R global environment, I copied R Workspace and R history from the 1st machine to the second.  While the R workspace opens in the second machine, all programs run very slow or throws error.  Can someone educate?

Comment: Try saving as `.RData` file and load that in second system instead of copying.

Comment: 1) try using R-Studio unless there is some major factor because of which you can't . 2) you need two things to port your work to any machine- the .Rdata file + the .r script.